# How to find badge of a tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, badges, tag-badges

For example, with Flutter, I have manually go to the tag's top user, and go through there badges, to get

https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7013/flutter (bronze)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7311/flutter (silver)
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/7924/flutter (gold)

Is there an easy way for me to find badge of any tag, such as "java" or "ios"

Answer (score 3):

The page you're looking for is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=all) (warning: very slow to load!).

You get here by clicking on the trophy dropdown in the top bar, then "badges", then "bronze badge", then the "all" tab. From there, just use your browser's find ability (usually <kbd>control + f</kbd>) to get to the right badge.

Comment: so there is no filter, either in UI or URL? that's quite sad...